# How to remove type="text/css" property from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-loadable

The library (@loadable/server) that I am using is returning `<style type='text/css'> <my styles here> </style>` and I would like to remove the `type='text/css'`from there.

The reason is that the W3C validator is raising a warning:

> The type attribute for the style element is not needed and should be omitted

I am trying to remove it using regex without success since it is a raw string.

```
function getInlineStyleTags() {
   <some logic here>
   ...
   return `<style type='text/css' data-chunk='${asset.chunk}'>${data}</style>`
}
```

```
styleTags = getInlineStyleTags()
```

I expect to remove from my variable `styleTags` the `type='text/css'` by regex or other approach.

Comment: You want to remove just the type attribute ?
`<style type='text/css'>my styles here</style> --> <style>my styles here</style>`

Comment: @Neekobus yes, just the type attribute.

Comment: Running W3C validator it is raising a warning: `The type attribute for the style element is not needed and should be omitted`.

Comment: So you cannot modify `return \`<style type='text/css' data-chunk='${asset.chunk}'>${data}</style>\`` to omit the attribute?

Comment: @andrehigher — It's a warning, not an error, and if you want to change it you should do so at the source rather then having code which adds it then other code which removes it.

Comment: @mplungjan I cannot modify this piece of code since it is an external library.

Comment: `styleTags = getInlineStyleTags().replace("type='text/css'", '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do that but I guess a simple `replace` will work :

```
var styleWithoutAttr = styleTags.replace("type='text/css'", '')
```

And if you want to handle the possibility of simple or double quotes you can do :

```
var styleWithoutAttr = styleTags.replace("type=['\"]text/css['\"]", '')
```

Comment: @andrehigher You have to match to the quotes used (simple or doubles), or use the second variant that handle both.

Comment: It does not work. `'<style type="text/css"> body{border: 1px} </style>'.replace("type=['\"]text/css['\"]", '')` provides the same string.

Comment: Because .replace does not run on the original string. You need to do `styleTags = styleTags.replace(...)` or `styleTags= getInlineStyleTags().replace(...)`

Comment: @mplungjan I've just added the new variable assignement

Comment: I was thinking about a complex solution using regex but just a replace work well. Thank you @Neekobus

Comment: the second proposition is actually a regex, to handle the 2 types of quotes @andrehigher. You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the string styleTags with ''

```
styleTags=styleTags.replace(`type='text/css'`,'')
```